# webpack/babel transpilation removing object keys

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack/babel to transpile code, but for some reason, a third party package is having some code removed.

The third party code has a const defined similar to the following in its source:

```js
const NOUNS = {
  people: {
    a: [1, 2],
    b: [3, 4],
  },
  places: {
    a: [5, 6],
    b: [7, 8],
  },
};
```

The babel compilation step for that package uses runtime-corejs3 to ultimately output the following:

```js
import _defineProperty from '@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/defineProperty';

var NOUNS = {
  people: (
    _people = {},
    /*#__PURE__*/_defineProperty(_people, 'a', [1, 2]),
    /*#__PURE__*/_defineProperty(_people, 'b', [3, 4]),
    _people
  ),
  places: (
    _places = {},
    /*#__PURE__*/_defineProperty(_places, 'a', [5, 6]),
    /*#__PURE__*/_defineProperty(_places, 'b', [7, 8]),
    _places
  ),
};
```

Things look good so far, given that the `_defineProperty` import appears to delegate to `Object.defineProperty`.

However, once I run webpack on my own project, the resulting code ends up looking more like the following:

```js
pa = {
  people: (zn = {},
    'a',
    1,
    2,
    'b',
    3,
    4,
    zn),
  places: (wn = {},
    'a',
    5,
    6,
    'b',
    7,
    8,
    zn)
}
```

Essentially, the `_defineProperty` calls have been treated as no-ops, as they're now lost, and the arguments passed to those calls are just being treated as individual commands that do nothing.  The result is that the objects are empty, and I basically end up with this:

```js
var NOUNS = {
  people: {},
  places: {},
};
```

It's unclear to me what in my babel transpilation is causing this to happen.  Happy to share more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  The package includes `babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls` in its build, which it probably needs to exclude.  That is what's adding the `#__PURE__` comments, which in turn get removed during my app's webpack/babel transpilation.